# Raising exception during SQLite database connection in Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Here is my code snippet:-

```
import sqlite3
database = "sample.db"
def dbConnection(database):
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
        db_cursor = connection.cursor()
        db_cursor.execute("show tables;")
        rows = db_cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print row
        connection.close()
    except sqlite3.Error, e:
        print "Error in connection",e
dbConnection("enb.db")
```

It is raising this exception:-

```
Error in connection near "show": syntax error
```

I can't see anything wrong with the syntax as I just want to view the tables in the database. What could be the problem here?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SHOW TABLES" is not supported by SQLite. 
It is valid for other databases such as MySQL.

[SQLite sql reference](http://sqlite.org/lang.html)

[How to 'show tables' in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-do-i-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't support "show" functions. You can use `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master where type='table'`. I found it from this thread, [Android sqlite show tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647129/android-sqlite-show-tables)